# Reordering UICollectionView cells in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview

I need to implement a reordering functionality in `UICollectionView`, like reordering cells in `UITableView`. Looking for a Swift implementation.

In reordering state of the `collectionView`, one cell should be able to drag and drop to an other position, and then a delegate would be called to modify datasource accordingly.

Do you know any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Custom `collectionView` layout `LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout` at the [GitHub](https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout) does support what you want, but it is written in `Objective-C`